# making part of a statement iterative in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, iteration, foreach-loop-container

I have a lookup that works for a single column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$145,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$145,0)),"")
```

If **A2** matches the range of values in **D2 to D145**, then output the corresponding **C2 to C145** value in cell **B2**

This populates column **B2** successfully.

How could I put that into a loop, so that `$D2:$D145` iterates between **column D** and **column GS**

Really appreciate any hints from anyone at this point.

Comment: Formulas and loops just don't go together. In such situation you have to choose: to go with loops and VBA, or to stay with "pure" Excel and rethink your task (maybe calculate in multiple columns, do some manual processing etc.)

Comment: Do you mean you still want a single result but you want to search for A2 in the whole range D2:GS145?

Answer (score 0):

if its possible add column after gs and fill it with hlookup fomulas and then match by this column

hlookup formula for GT2:

```
=iferror(hlookup(a$2,indirect("D"&row(gt2)&":GS"&row(gt2)),1,0),"")
```

and copypaste it down until GT145; and your formula changes to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$145,MATCH(A2,$GT$2:$GT$145,0)),"")
```